# How to solve memory access violation exception

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, mingw-w64

**Background**

I have built my application which has following control flow :--

Managed C++ DLL (compiler - VS2015, OS- windows 7) -> C++ library (compiler - VS2015, OS - windows 7) -> C library (VS 2015 - win 7) -> C library (compiler - gcc (minGW) - windows 10).

I am facing access memory violation error in c++ library in our test virtual machine (windows 7 with VS2015 run time environment). Same application is working fine on our development machine (windows 7 with VS 2015).

**Analysis**

As I am not able to reproduce this on my development machine, I can not debug the flow. I have tried first with `GetExceptioninformation()` which has given me following information :-

```
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000001271f0
Faulting process id: 0xedc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3e6e36e2cbda8
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\TMCVP0K3.2WC\VCW47EJV.PV7\26e400ac\00b47d69_f8e6d301\DarkMailEngine.DLL
Report Id: c4450271-52d6-11e8-a558-080027fa51ab
```

As a second approach I have run the WinDBG on my test machine and it has given me following stack trace :--

```
FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!RtlSizeHeap+89
00000000`77506789 0fb74118        movzx   eax,word ptr [rcx+18h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000077506789 (ntdll!
+0x0000000000000089)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000f8668c7dd18
Attempt to read from address 00000f8668c7dd18

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000000000006d0

PROCESS_NAME:  OUTLOOK.EXE

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000f8668c7dd18

READ_ADDRESS:  00000f8668c7dd18 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ntdll!RtlSizeHeap+89
00000000`77506789 0fb74118        movzx   eax,word ptr [rcx+18h]

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: 
(TransitionMU)
000000002C02DEC0 000007FE8DD156FB UNKNOWN!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(sqlite3*, Void*, Int32)+0x7b
000000002C02DF70 000007FE8DD1565C DarkMailEngine!<Module>.DarkMatter.Client.Internal.CppSQLite3DB.setPassword(DarkMatter.Client.Internal.CppSQLite3DB*, SByte*)+0x4c
000000002C02DFA0 000007FE8DD14842 DarkMailEngine!<Module>.DarkMatter.Client.Internal.ModelStore.initialize(DarkMatter.Client.Internal.ModelStore*, std.vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> >*)+0x152
000000002C02E0D0 000007FE8DD1420D DarkMailEngine!<Module>.DarkMatter.Client.Internal.ModelStore.initialize(DarkMatter.Client.Internal.ModelStore*)+0x9d
000000002C02E1E0 000007FE8DD13EA9 DarkMailEngine!<Module>.DarkMatter.Client.Internal.DatabaseOpenManager.{ctor}(DarkMatter.Client.Internal.DatabaseOpenManager*)+0x49
000000002C02E220 000007FE8DD188D9 DarkMailEngine!<Module>.DarkMatter.Client.Internal.ModelStore.getSetting(DarkMatter.Client.Internal.ModelStore*, std.vector<std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> >,std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >*, std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >*, std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >*)+0x99
```

Can somebody please suggest how can I fix this issue or what can be possible reasons for this issue.

Comment: Extract a [mcve]. Yes, that's an enormous step, but without it, your question is useless. Nobody here is going to be able to tell you where the fault is in that code which they don't know.

Comment: Ok.. let me rephrase my question...

Comment: No hope of plugging in and performing a remote debug?

Comment: As of now, it is very hard as test machine in different environment.. But I am trying in parallel if we can do it... Any other way apart from it ?

Comment: This looks like a unmanaged heap corruption. Try enabling page heap to get more information. Check out the gflags utility.

Comment: Finally issue has been resolved using debug build. There were multiple reasons like header mismatch, unlocking thread without locking it etc.